eclipse m2e use client certs for https
My goal is to have eclipse m2e access a corporate Artifactory instance using client certs and NOT have other things that I run from eclipse use those certs.
In IntelliJ it's really easy, you can set the VM options for the Maven runner only.
One approach for eclipse that I tried was to create a JRE with the "Default VM arguments" to point to those client certs, but I can't see how to get m2e to use that JRE unless it's the default JRE.
TBC, I'm not attached to this solution.  Just that when I run maven from eclipse I use those certs, and when I run anything else, I don't.
Thank you very much.

In Eclipse, in a Maven run configuration, you can set the JRE/JDK to be used to run the Maven build in the JRE tab.

Ok, that does work, thank you.  But is there a way to set that as a default for maven builds?  Right now I have to add the cert arguments for each maven build that I create.  And I like throwing together quick test apps so I'd have to do that a few times a day.

Sharing those Maven run configurations (see run configuration Common tab) would avoid everyone having to configure their IDE. Otherwise, in the preference Maven > Java Configuration, I don't see an option to set default VM arguments for Maven. So if you need it, please provide a pull request here.
